# Plastic shower drain filter

Tags: shower, replacement, plastic, filter

How do you replace the plastic shower filter. I cannot get it to snap back into the black rubber gasket.

Comment: Some photos would be helpful

Comment: Is the drain filter a replacement? For a tub or a stall? Are there tabs that enabled it to attach to the drain? Is this filter an accessory you added? Pictures would produce more accurate answers.